# How do I properly set routes up for a Single Page App using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

I am attempting to build a single page app using Express.js.  On my index.html page, I have a basic form, which upon submit will make a request to an API, retrieve the data, parse it, and then I want to render the parsed data as a list of links.  Right now I am able to render the index page, and I can make the submission call to the API from the form that I added to the page.  What I am confused about is how to properly redirect the data I get from the API call and then render it on the same page.  I've built simple apps using Express before where there were multiple views, but never a single page app. For those apps, I know that for the response you could call something like res.render('name of view to render', data), but that is not working in this case. I've tried to find some solutions through this site and via the Express docs, but I have not seen anything that didn't also include using another framework like Angular.  For the purposes of this app, I need to not include any additional frameworks, and I am a bit lost.

My function for calling the API looks like this right now.  When it is called, I am directed to a page that just has the json displayed

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
  var title = req.query.movieTitle;
  var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + title;

  request(url, function (err, response, body) {
    var results = JSON.parse(body);
    var movieTitles = results.Search;
    console.log(movieTitles);
    res.send(movieTitles);
  });
});
```

Comment: Can u please add angular part?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my explanation, but I am actually NOT using angular, and am attempting to build this app without the use of any additional frameworks, such as Angular

Comment: you need to implement AJAX app for this atleast using JavaScript if you dont want to use angular or jQuery or React.AJAX is what single page app

Comment: I appreciate it, but it's important for this particular app to not use any additional libraries or frameworks.  Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: still you would need to implement something client side that makes the request to your api - AJAX is pretty much the minimum you have to use

Comment: I see.  Well, I will look into that more.  I'm supposed to use vanilla javascript for this

Answer (score 3):

The basic thing you have to do is:

- define routes which your back-end app has to respond with the spa
- send your "skeleton" file to the response on that routes

Example code:

```
const handler = (req, res) => res.send(path.join(__dirname, "path/to/your/index.html"))

const routes = ["/", "/hello", "/world"]

routes.forEach( route => app.get(route, handler) )
```

This should get you started

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and see if it works.  I'll update once I give it a shot.  Cheers

Comment: I tried implementing this, and I keep getting an error "Unexpected identifier" for 'handler'.  I know that the code you are using is the ES6 syntax, it shouldn't make a difference if I have something like that mixed in with my non-ES6 JS, right?

Comment: you probably should add the "use strict" line to the very top of your file or launch app with command "node --use_stritct myapp.js"